# articles before variables with names

Tags: articles

Is an article needed before a variable with a name, like, variable Z, in a text?
If you give a variable a name, it becones like a man, say, named John - and I am yet to see 'the man John'. But I often see 'the radius r', 'a distance d'. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the article is not needed.

The noun (*radius* etc.) is used as an [*appositive*](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/what_are_appositives.en.html) to name another noun (e.g. *r*) that is right next to it.

(This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/95393/4544) on ELL.)